# matplotlib histtype='step' looses data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a histogram using matplotlib, my code is bellow. In the second plot if i set the histtype='step' I loose three bins of the data and cannot work out why. Has anyone had this problem before? If I change the histtype='bar' the plot looks fine.See image attached.

Code 1:

```
plt.hist(DelB[Sp],bins=20,histtype='step',normed=True,label='Sp')
dd=np.concatenate((DelB[S0],DelB[E]))
plt.hist(dd,bins=15,color='g',histtype='step',normed=True,label='E+S0')
plt.xlim(0.4,2.3)
ylabel('normalized fraction',size=15)
plt.legend()
```

Code2:

```
plt.hist(DelB[Sp],bins=20,alpha=0.5,facecolor='blue',normed=True,label='Sp')
dd=np.concatenate((DelB[S0],DelB[E]))
plt.hist(dd,bins=15,alpha=0.5,facecolor='green',normed=True,label='E+S0')
plt.xlim(0.4,2.3)
plt.legend()
ylabel('normalized fraction',size=15)
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better to include a reproducible example code and/or images for us. At the moment your question is rather hard to answer.

Comment: I added the plots, but it would be too hard to add the data

Comment: okay, so if i remove normed=True then the plot works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your axis limits in the second plot are different. You can't see bars that are below the image boundary. Adding `plt.ylim(0,2)` will solve the issue

Comment: That's the reason why the plots are different. But it does not explain, why this actually happens.

Comment: @cel I have no idea how the automatic range determination works. But I know that you sometimes need to override it.

Comment: @Christoph, you may want to add setting a proper `ylim()` should solve this problem.

Comment: the yaxis started at 0.4.. not 0

Comment: @astrochris: I can only guess. I note that 0.4 is like the non-zero minimum of your green dataset. It may have taken that as a limit. For science you might try what happens if you change the order of the green and the blue plots and see if the ranges are determined differently.